# Community Analyst in Portal?

Tags: arcgis-online, community, enterprise

Does anybody know if there is a way to deploy Community Analyst in Portal?

We're in the process of migrating from ArcGIS Online to Portal, and would like our Online Community Analyst users to be able to move completely to the new enterprise environment.

I feel like there should be a way to integrate these two pieces of the platform together, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

Current we do not deliver a product as ‘Community Analyst app for on-premises’ however Business Analyst Web App (formerly known as BAO) is available both online and on-premises. Since BA Web App includes the exact same workflows and datasets as Community Analyst, it can be positioned to be used as Community Analyst on-premises. You can then use the app theme customization settings to label and brand the app as Community Analyst. http://doc.arcgis.com/en/business-analyst/web/set-preferences.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_A95D17A18E81405B90B65622FAD9DDAA